# Xcode Run Script NOT For Catalyst

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

[image]

I have a run script that is only for `iOS` and I do not want it to be run when I build for `Mac Catalyst`. Is there conditional code I can add into the run script to check this?

Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, and it was quite simple:

```
if [ "${TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST}" = "1" ]; then
bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/ZSS.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
fi
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me with Xcode 12.2, I had to use:
`if [ "${IS_MACCATALYST}" = "YES" ]; then`

Answer (score 0):

Nic Hubbard found a solution to his own question. Another way to solve this is by adding another target to the project for the Mac specific version of the app. This target can be a copy of the original iOS app target with the script removed.

This would increase the complexity of maintaining this project going forward. When you add something to the project you have to make sure it is added to both targets. You would also have to ensure the iOS and Mac apps are built with the correct targets.

Comment: Hmm, I would prefer not to add this complexity. Currently I have just been removing the build script when I need to build for macOS and adding it back for iOS.